# Eclipse style help system (SWT?)

Tags: eclipse, swt

I am writing a custom app that requires a help system.

The app is written in SWT.

Is there anyway I can generate eclipse style help with SWT?

I.e when you press F1 in the Eclipse editor you get a new window on the side.

As an aside, I would also like to be able to provide an editor for this help documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find instructions here: [Adding Help Support to a Rich Client Platform (RCP) Application](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-AddingHelpToRCP/index.html)

Comment: it seems that this tutorial is a little old... I cant get the plug-in app to load the help page (after adding the org.eclipse.help dependency) any other tips?

Comment: @geejay: Any errors logged if you pass `-consolelog` as a program argument in your run configuration? Also, you could try adding the help extension via the wizard (MANIFEST.MF -> Extensions -> Add... -> Extension Wizards -> Help Content). Just tried that with Galileo (Eclipse 3.5) and the new help page shows up in the *Help* menu if I choose *Help Contents*.

Comment: Thanks for the help Fabian, i actually got it working, I didn't add the required dependencies properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into Eclipse RCP for helpview.